# How do I tailor my query to get a specific title?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a query in my `app.js` file that renders into my list page `list.ejs`  found at `http://localhost:4100/list`. As the name may suggest, the `list` page displays a list of **ALL** the transactions stored in the database, though I would be more interested in only displaying all the transactions strictly within the **county** of **Nairobi**.

Find below the contents of my `app.js` file:

```
app.get('/list', (req,res)=> {

let countyName;
countyName = transModel.findOne({ transCounty : /Nairobi/i, })
                                    .limit(5)
                                    .select({ transCounty:1})
                                    .exec( (err, result)=> {
                                        
                                    if (err) throw err;
                                           console.log('>> ' +result); 
                                           return result;
                                        });
                                        
console.log ('countyName: ' +countyName);

transModel.find( (err, docs)=> {
if (!err) 
    {
        res.render('list',  {data : docs, countyName: countyName}); 
    }
else
    {
//          res.status(status).send(body);      
    }
        
 })

});
```

In the terminal, the code above yeilds:

```
countyName: undefined
>> { _id: 609f7ed8fe1fd8b3193b0b77, transCounty: 'Nairobi' }
```

My `list.ejs` looks like this:

```
<h1> Transactions </h1>

<p>
 Name of County: <%= countyName %>  
</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th> _id  </th>
        <th> Transaction Amount </th>       
        <th> Transaction County </th>       
        <th> Transaction Industry </th> 
    </tr>
    <% data.forEach(function(entry) {%>
    <tr>
        <td> <%=entry._id%> </td> 
        <td> <%=entry.transAmount%> </td>       
        <td> <%=entry.transCounty%> </td>       
        <td> <%=entry.transIndustry%> </td>     
    </tr>
    <%});%>
    
</table>
```

The above `list.ejs` file, though correctly renders a table with the desired content from the database isn't able to pick the name of the **County**.  Kindly help me figure out how I can achieve this.

Find below an image of the rendered `list.ejs`:
[image: the rendered list.ejs]

Kindly note **Name of county** is **undefined**.
How do I formulate my query be able to yield all transactions within only Nairobi, and also display the name of the county in the ejs file.

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: you don't wait for the promise to resolve. what ORM do you use?

Comment: @Michael thanks, how do I wait for the promise to resolve? Can you kindly give me an example in code?

Comment: What orm do you use?

Comment: @Michael Sorry, I use the Mongoose ORM

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the promise to resolve before using its value:

```
countyName = await transModel.findOne({
        transCounty: /Nairobi/i,
    })
    .limit(5)
    .select({
        transCounty: 1
    })
    .exec();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Having updated my code according to your advice, I now seem to be getting `[object Promise]` issues. Kindly follow here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67670183/how-do-i-resolve-object-promise-caused-from-an-async-function